# SQL statement runs fine when copied into mysql> but when it is run as a script I get a Error 1064

Tags: mysql

I have an SQL script file that creates a table.  The second half populates the table.  If I copy and paste the code from the script directly to the `msql>` prompt, it runs fine.  However if I try to run it as a script file I get an `Error 1064`

I have run each section of the code on its own and they work fine.

```
CREATE TABLE project1.Friends (FriendID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
      ,FNAME varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL
      ,LNAME varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL
      ,dob date DEFAULT NULL
      ,PRIMARY KEY (FriendID));

INSERT INTO Friends (FNAME, LNAME,dob) VALUES 
     ('Joe', 'Brown', '1963-01-04')
    ,('Brian', 'Green', '1986-07-29')
    ,('Pete', 'Gray', '1980-06-22')
     ,('Ed', 'Mitchell' ,'1965-11-15');
```

I expect the table to be created and populated.  When code is run as a script I get an error.

Comment: If you read the description that accompanies the error, it usually gives a really good clue as to where MySQL is having a problem with your query. My initial, blind, guess would be that perhaps the default/current db is not "project1" when the script is run; meaning the INSERT is attempting to insert into a "Friends" table in a different database where it may not exist, or exists in with a different structure.

Comment: Show the script. What language is the script in?

Comment: So in MySQL, this error comes whenever there is any syntax error in the query. Share the script so that syntax can be verified.